# Not able to insert INT data in Python using MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using MySQL connector in Python and trying to insert an integer data, but I keep getting this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

My code looks like this:

```
medDosage = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, '42mg')))

myCursor.execute("INSERT INTO dosage (dosageDesc) VALUES (%s)", medDosage)
db.commit()
```

And this statement has been working just fine for all other variables, and somehow for INT value, it does not work. I tried inserting the string variable instead of int, but doesn't work. Also tried to convert the value such as `int(medDosage)` to make sure it's the right type, but still doesn't work. I know my syntax is correct so I cannot really understand the error. Can you please help why this error is showing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: prefer using `myCursor.executemany` as being more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the last argument is a tuple:

```py
myCursor.execute("INSERT INTO dosage (dosageDesc) VALUES (%s)", (medDosage,))
```

Comment: Omg thank you, I can't believe I wasted so much time on this. I will accept as answer soon as I can (10 min left)

Comment: @sarahkim Easy thing to omit, especially with one argument.